# Certificate not showing in localhost i.e. imagecreatefromjpeg() not working

Tags: php, php-gd, imagecreatefrompng, imagecreatefromjpg

I want to create certificates for users on my website but following code isn't working and only showing grey square when loaded on localhost...

```
<?php
header('content-type:image/jpeg');
$font="BRUSHSCI.TTF";
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg("certificate.jpg");
$color=imagecolorallocate($image,19,21,22);
$name="Name";
imagettftext($image,50,0,365,420,$color,$font,$name);
$date="12th may 2021";
imagettftext($image,20,0,450,595,$color,"AGENCYR.TTF",$date);
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

This output I got when I run above code:
[image: This output I got when I run above code]

Comment: You should look in the webserver error log for php errors, or use  `error_reporting(E_ALL)` upfront to show potential errors.

Comment: no no error, it only shows above output no error log....

Comment: It shows no errors in your browser, but have you checked the error log? Or have you used the `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and then refreshed?

Comment: yeah Mr. I did But same output.... Let me know, whether imagecreatefromjpeg work on php 7 or not?

Comment: Your code looks fine...The problem is probably because you have something before the PHP...1.you need to remove everything before the <?php tag even a space will cause problems 2.Make sure your certificate jpg and fonts exists in the folder

Comment: imagecreatefromjpeg will work in any version of php, as long as GD is installed. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php